# Dependent visa for France

Tags: france, dependent-visa

I'm Swathi and recently entered France on a student visa, for a 2 year program. The visa is for one year only and then I'll need to extend my stay.

I want to know if my spouse can join me in France on a dependent visa now. as I have been a resident for exactly one month, or should I wait a few months? If my spouse comes here, can he work full or part-time on a dependent visa?

Comment: Why would you wait?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that a student visa in France gives any right for a spouse dependent visa.

Comment: Some clues here : https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2209

Comment: @audionuma It does, it's [explicitly listed here](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2209). Problem is that you need to document income above the full-time minimal wage, which might be difficult for a student (and it's also illegal to work full-time on a student title so that income must come from something else than a full-time minimal-wage job). And you also need a place larger than 22-28 sqm, so larger than a typical student residence accommodation.

Answer (score 1):

It is in principle possible to have your spouse join you while you stay in France on foot of a student permit. Your can apply for that after having resided for 18 months in France and there are a number of other conditions regarding [income and accommodation](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11166) that might be hard to meet for the average student. Dependents on a long-stay visa or [“vie privée et familiale” residence permit](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2209) are allowed to work.

Comment: Regroupement familial : "L'étranger, à l'origine du regroupement, doit résider depuis au moins 18 mois en France" looks like a delay, doesn't it ?

Comment: @audionuma Indeed, forgot about that, answer edited. I was under the impression it was possible to move with your family immediately but it could be that you need to apply for that before coming to France or that I am just confused.