# My wife is going for an advanced master's course in France. Will I get a dependent visa to accompany her? What are my options?

Tags: visa, france

The Advanced Masters course is for a duration of one year. My current job, based out of India, allows me the flexibility of working remotely so I will not be looking for employment within France.

If there is no provision for a dependent visa, then what other options do I have?

Can I travel on a tourist visa and continue to work remotely for my employer in India?

Would appreciate if I can get specific information w.r.t France. Thanks.

Comment: On a tourist visa, you can spend no more than 90 days in every 180-day period in the Schengen area.  I suspect that this isn't enough time for you.

Comment: Note that although you work remotely, you will actually be working in France (in the eye of the french law). So you need a status with work permit.

Comment: There are dependent visas for student visas, which generally do not allow for work. Dependent visas for scientists do allow for work (this is the visa she'd get for a PhD but not a Masters). Generally the dependent visa will be predicated upon her ability to support herself + you. So this may be difficult.
You would have to be set up as an auto-entrepreneur to work in France, though I'm not sure how that works with working remotely.

Comment: Some info here https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/dependent-visa-for-france